# Order sheets in google spreadsheet by creation date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Actually what I am doing is, I have google spreadsheet with more than 20 sheets in it. But the sheets are shuffled. Is there any way to order these sheets by date of creation?

Is there any function in google scripts to get creation date of a specific sheet in google spreadsheet?

Comment: Don't think you can find the creation date. However pretty sure they get an index that increases each time. So by looking at the array `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()` you should be able to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't retrieve the creation date of individual sheets, but as a workaorund you can view the version history

- This is possible both from the UI and Apps Script (whereby the first is easier)
- From the UI - go to `File->Version history - > See version history`
- now, when you click the past versions, you can trace back what the spreadsheet looked like before the sheets were shuffled