# Auto advance to newest tab at certain time of day

Tags: google-apps-script

Almost zero experience with programming, except finding examples of useful codes online that I can customize through extensive searches...with that said, I have a google Sheet that I use as a job board, and I need it to auto advance to the newest tab (that I have already created) at a certain time of the morning. I have seen some scripts that come near what I'd like to do but not close enough. I don't want to create a new tab at a certain time, just advance from one tab to the next. All help and comments will be appreciated, thank you all!

I found this script and was trying to get it to do what I wanted, I see that it is triggering something at a certain time of the day but I do not know what it is triggering

```
function myFunction() {
    // Trigger every Wednesday at 7:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
      .atHour(7)
      .create();
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling newTrigger inside the function that you want it to trigger. Try defining your function: `function myFunction() { alert('whee!'); }`, then calling the ScriptApp.newTrigger outside of that.

Comment: Once you've done that, then you can replace `alert('whee!');` with the code to advance from one tab to the next.

Comment: OP script is from documentation [Managing triggers programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). Though with errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order sheets in google spreadsheet by creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62320844/order-sheets-in-google-spreadsheet-by-creation-date)

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display a particular tab when you open the Spreadsheet?

Comment: `ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')`-`but I do not know what it is triggering`. It is flawed; it is trying to trigger itself!! You creating an installable trigger [programatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).  Look at the documentation: there should be **two** functions. #1: `createTimeDrivenTriggers` is the script that will create the installable trigger; 
#2: `'myFunction'` is the triggered script that you want to run every Wednesday at 7. In your script, `myFunction` is used for both script names.

Comment: You want to `auto advance to the newest tab`. Google sheets doesn't keep track of the date/time that any given sheet was created. So for a person with "zero experience with programming", it's not possible to identify the _newest_ sheet. However if you provide more information about how your spreadsheet, how you name your sheets, whether you do (or can) enter the creation date in a cell on each sheet, or on a separate sheet sheet, etc... then perhaps we can find a workaround.